# Print author details for a node

Tags: 8, theming, nodes

How do I print the author details for a node? In particular, I am interested to the following values.

- Author picture
- Name
- Description

In Drupal 7, I would use this code.

```
<?php print $author_data['picture'];?>
<?php print $author_data['name']; ?>
<?php print $author_data['description']?>
```

What is the equivalent in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see the available variables at the top of the twig file, two are already there:

> - author_picture: The node author user entity, rendered using the "compact"
> - author_name: Themed author name field.

For other fields of the author you can print the field value:

```
{{ node.Owner.name.value }}
```

And description, if you have added this field to user:

```
{{ node.Owner.description.value }}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I understent.  And to added field to user I need to write simple module or there is easier way?

Comment: I found /admin/config/people/accounts/fields.. :)

Comment: As an alternative, Drupal core also automatically provides the compact view mode, author_picture is actually that. See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/8. That means you can control which fields are shown there and can also provide a custom template for that, then you can re-use that in many different node templates and don't have to duplicate all the markup.

Answer (score 10):

This is what worked for me in the node template for any custom field:

```
{{ node.uid.entity.field_name.value }}
```

I'm using Drupal 8.3.7

**EDIT:**
This is what I'm doing for the profile picture. 
I'm creating a rendering object so I can specify a theme and an image style:

```
            {% set imagestyle = {
              '#theme':      'image_style',
              '#style_name': 'user_avatar_80x80',
              '#uri':        node.uid.entity.user_picture.entity.uri.value,
              '#attributes': { class: 'authorImg' },
            } %}
            <div class="authorCol1">{{ imagestyle }}</div>
```

Comment: What does it mean to be un Drupal 8.3.7?

Comment: 8.3.7 is the version of Drupal that he is using.  Specifying the particular version is helpful as things sometimes change between versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<span>{{ 'Author: '|t ~ author_name|striptags }}</span>` in Drupal 8.